# HTML / CSS Icon sizes

Tags: html, css

In the screenshot below we can see 3 icons - 2 of them of the same size, and one(left one) appears bigger/uneven to the 2 others. 
[image]

This is my HTML code part for this bit:

```
  <article class="number">
                          <div class="number__illu" style="margin-top: -33px">
                             <picture class="picture picture--no-background" style="padding-bottom: 146.875%"><img src="assets/images/svg/location-pointer.svg"></picture>
                          </div>
                          <h4>Header</h4>
                          <p>Part 1</p>
                       </article>

                       <article class="number">
                          <div class="number__illu" style="margin-bottom: -10px">
                             <picture class="picture picture--no-background" style="padding-bottom: 125.35%"><img src="assets/images/svg/world.svg"></picture>
                          </div>
                          <h4>Header</h4>
                          <p>Part 2</p>
                       </article>

                       <article class="number">
                          <div class="number__illu" style="margin-top: 14px">
                             <picture class="picture picture--no-background"><img src="assets/images/svg/users.svg"></picture>
                          </div>
                          <h4>Header</h4>
                          <p>Part 3</p>
                       </article>
```

And this is the CSS part that goes along with it:

```
.about__section__numbers .number {
margin: 30px auto;
text-align: center
}

.about__section__numbers .number__illu {
max-width: 100px;
margin: 0 auto 10px
}
```

I don't see why the icon on the left appears bigger than the 2 others.

Comment: Screenshots do not work.

Comment: Your images are SVG, if you want help with these SVGs in particular then post the real urls. There are a 1000 things going on in a SVG (even the simple ones).

Comment: Is there a real reason for using .svg for such simple icon? You may want to try out FontAwesome or similar. You can style them with css

Answer (score 2):

you have different padding and margins hard-written onto each of your elements. removing that will likely help you troubleshoot better.

try a debug style like *{ outline: 1px solid red; } to help you see if the boxes are sized properly.

alternately you can also try picture,image {display:inline-block}

Answer (score 0):

It's because the images have different widths compared to their heights. You should set the height to a specific pixel height to make them look the same size.

Or you could artificially add white space to the sides of the larger icon so that it has the same native width as the other two icons.